# How to keep the first space in Cell on a .xlt

Tags: vba, excel

I worked on an export of data from an ERP to Excel but I encoutered a problem.
When I received my datas on my model Excel (.xlt, i don't have a choice for the extension...), all first spaces of fields in the ERP disappeared on my worksheet...

An exemple (Here, spaces before "Holder") :

[image: On my ERP]

And now, on excel, without spaces... :

[image: On excel]

And the last information, I think the problem is only on file type .xlt (97/03) (The only one I can use of course...) because when I try an export in .xls, there is no problem.

I already tried to change the type of cell in `Text` or `Standard` but it doesn't work.

Did you have a solution ?
Thanks !

Comment: My guess is that the export function is messed up. Are you intesreted in a macro that post-processes the xlt to fix the spaces?

Comment: I think too, but i'm only the trainee so I can't access to the parameters...
In fact I didn't try macro post-processes because sometimes, there is a space, and sometimes there isn't. So I don't know how to distinguish the cells which need a processing...
EDIT : And if the export function is messed up, why does the xls work ?

Comment: I assume when you export you choose the format - so in the ERP there is a seperate function for export xls and export xlt - I guessing there's a bug in the "export xlt." If you want help writing the macro you'll have to post more info.

Comment: In fact, we can not choose the format because if we want to export in Excel (We can also export in word or xml), we are forced to export in .xlt, because there are some macros on my xlt file. It's little complicated to explain, but the export work well... Can we modify options of a xlt ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me outline a typical solution:

1. You have a "data source" you cannot control - in this case it's an xlt file that somewhere on your hard drive - call it export1.xlt
2. You want to add the data from a data source (export1.xlt) to a "database" which could just be another aggregate spreadsheet or whatever. Let's call it database1.xlsx.

   3. Typcially you would create a marcro inside database1.xlsx that knows how to import data into intself - in this case let's say you give a path e.g. C:\temp\export1.xlt and tell it to copy that data to Sheet1.
   4. When you run that macro it will open export1.xlt, read the data into Sheet1 of database1.xlsx, and perform any necessary post-processing.
   5. In this case the post processing could simply be looping over every cell to looking for a missing space.